# Pair two arrays into one associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I have two arrays:

```
SUBJECT_IDS=(44456 11123 77789)
DCM_FILES=("./77789/77789/"DICOM"" "./11123/11123/"DICOM"" "./44456/44456/77789/"DICOM"" )
```

Which I then sorted to make the indexing easier/already sort of 'pair' it by index:

```
IFS=$'\n'
sorted_SUBJECT_IDS=($(sort <<<"${SUBJECT_IDS[*]}"))
sorted_DCM_FILES=($(sort <<<"${DCM_FILES[*]}"))
```

***How would I create an associative array by pairing the two arrays by indice?***

```
headers=(
    [11123]=./11123/11123/DICOM
    [44456]=./44456/44456/DICOM
    [77789]=./77789/77789/DICOM
)
```

Here are my attempts at creating an associative array:

### Attempt 1:

```
declare -A headers
i=0
for i in "${sorted_SUBJECT_IDS[@]}"
do
  headers["$i"]="${sorted_DCM_FILES[i]}";
  echo "$i" : "${sorted_DCM_FILES[i]}"
  ((i++))
done
```

*Output:*

```
11123 :
44456 :
77789 :
```

## Attempt 2:

```
typeset -A hash
hash=("$(@){sorted_SUBJECT_IDS:^sorted_DCM_FILES}")
```

Output:

```
bash: hash: "$(@){sorted_SUBJECT_IDS:^sorted_DCM_FILES}": mustuse subscript when assigning associative array
```

Comment: Since your indices are numerical, you could use a normal (sparse) array instead, any specific reason you want an associative array?

Comment: +Benjamin W. I’m creating a table of subject IDs and File Locations (along with other file information) for later use. For bookeeping purposes. Figured an associative key would be easier to populate the table.

Comment: Why are you putting the `DICOM` strings outside quotes? Is your intention actually to have literal double quotes in these places?

Comment: +tripleee it's a hierarchy of my workspace where the general set up is: ID/ID/DICOM/. The subdirectory DICOM has the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort` is not working the way you want it to be and moreover your array iteration should be by the index not by items.

You may use:

```
sorted_SUBJECT_IDS=($(sort -n <(printf '%s\n' "${SUBJECT_IDS[@]}")))
sorted_DCM_FILES=($(sort -n <(printf '%s\n' "${DCM_FILES[@]}")))

declare -A headers

for i in "${!sorted_SUBJECT_IDS[@]}"; do 
   headers["${sorted_SUBJECT_IDS[i]}"]="${sorted_DCM_FILES[i]}"
done

# check header associative array

declare -p headers
```

```
declare -A headers=([77789]="./77789/77789/DICOM" [44456]="./44456/44456/77789/DICOM" [11123]="./11123/11123/DICOM" )
```

Comment: +anubhava Your code works the way you showed me, except I'm not able to access any values from the keys. For example, `echo ${headers[77789]}` gives me no output.

Comment: When I do `echo ${headers[77789]}` I get `./77789/77789/DICOM` in my shell. Are you sure you're not running above code in a subshell?

Comment: I'm sure. Here's my output of `declare -p headers `: `declare -A headers='([77789]="./77789/77789/DICOM" [44456]="./44456/44456/77789/DICOM" [11123]="./11123/11123/DICOM" )'`. So, I take back my previous comment - for some reason I have single quotes surrounding the entire output which then causes this issue.

Comment: no, the problem is I don't think I'm even getting an associative array from `declare -P headers`

Comment: You can see a working demo: https://ideone.com/MW99zM and it is `declare -p headers` with lowercase `p`